# Using the Command Pattern with Parameters

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a ReloadableWeapon class like this:

```
public class ReloadableWeapon {

    private int numberofbullets;
    
    public ReloadableWeapon(int numberofbullets){
        this.numberofbullets = numberofbullets;
    }
    
    public void attack(){
        numberofbullets--;
    }
    
    public void reload(int reloadBullets){
        this.numberofbullets += reloadBullets;
    }
}
```

with the following `interface`:

```
public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

and use it like so:

```
public class ReloadWeaponCommand implements Command {

    private int reloadBullets;
    private ReloadableWeapon weapon;
    
    // Is is okay to specify the number of bullets?
    public ReloadWeaponCommand(ReloadableWeapon weapon, int bullets){
        this.weapon = weapon;
        this.reloadBullets = bullets;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        weapon.reload(reloadBullets);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
ReloadableWeapon chargeGun = new ReloadableWeapon(10);
Command reload = new ReloadWeaponCommand(chargeGun,10);
ReloadWeaponController controlReload = new  ReloadWeaponController(reload);
controlReload.executeCommand();
```

I was wondering, with the command `pattern`, with the examples I've seen, other than the object that the command is acting on, there are no other `parameters`.

[This example, alters the execute method to allow for a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104918/command-pattern-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-command).

[Another example, more close to what I have here, with parameters in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862888/get-result-of-executed-method-in-command-pattern?rq=1).

Is it bad practice/code smell to include parameters in the command `pattern`, in this case the `constructor` with the number of bullets?

Comment: The command pattern says only that there's an object that encapsulates all the info necessary to execute the command, e.g., parameters. Like on the Wikipedia page: "This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method parameters." It'd be a pretty useless pattern if you couldn't include any data :/

Comment: @DaveNewton - Essentially, wiki is saying it's okay to pass the number of bullets to reload command in the constructor? If I understand correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Command pattern by passing to it runtime params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187330/how-to-use-command-pattern-by-passing-to-it-runtime-params)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very purpose of this pattern is to allow to define actions, and to execute them later, once or several times.

The code you provide is a good example of this pattern : you define the action "reload", that charges the `gun` with an amount of `bullets=10` ammunition.

Now, if you decide to modify this code to add `bullets` as a parameter, then you completely lose the purpose of this pattern, because you will have to define the amount of ammunition every time.

IMHO, you can keep your code as it is. You will have to define several `ReloadWeaponCommand` instances, with different value of `bullets`. Then you may have to use another pattern (such as [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) to switch between the commands.

Comment: If I know each bullet is 10 and will never change, it's okay, correct, but if I want to give different capacity bullets, then Strategy pattern is better, correct?

Comment: I disagree. This is a perfect example of a command with parameters.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Just for my understanding, wiki confirmed that it's okay to include parameter(number of bullets) in the constructor to be invoked at a later time, correct? my code okay?

Comment: @DaveNewton, you may have misread this answer. It agrees with the OP. Then it mentions one potential consequence of the pattern, with regards to varying the state of the Command instance. I think we all agree, _This is a perfect example of a command with parameters._

Comment: @jaco0646 I don’t think I did. Answer states that adding the number of bullets means switching patterns, and *adding* a pattern, to support the number of bullets parameter. I disagree.

Comment: @DaveNewton, it says that choosing between multiple Command instances _may_ (not must) use an additional pattern (adding to the Command pattern, not replacing it). I think the last sentence is more of an afterthought, and if you agree on the remainder then we are on the same page.

Comment: @jaco0646 Whatever--this truly isn't worth discussing. The notion that adding a parameter to a command "loses the purpose" of the pattern or that there's any need to "switch between the commands" is just wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton, adding a parameter to the `execute()` method of a Command loses the purpose of the pattern. That is the point of the OP and this answer.

Comment: @jaco0646 And I'm saying I disagree; there is zero reason a command can't have context, and there's zero reason that context has to be an argument to `execute`.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I agree.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think adding parameters into **execute** will be bad design or violate command pattern.

It totally depends on how you want to use Command Object:  **Singleton Or Prototype** scope.

If you use Prototype scope, you can pass command parameters in Constructor methods. Each command instance has its own parameters.

If you use Singleton scope (shared/reused instance), you can pass command parameters in execute method. The singleton of the command should be thread safe for this case. This solution is a friend of IoC/DI framework too.

Comment: The GoF Command Pattern does not allow parameters to be passed to the `execute` method. That defeats the purpose of the pattern, because the Invoker then requires logic of how to call the Command, and commands are not interchangeable. Java's quintessential Command interfaces are [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). It is no accident these APIs do not take parameters.

Comment: @jaco0646: Well. GoF can have varieties. Important thing is the pattern must be working/trusted and applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a case you have 95 bullets in hand in starting, and you have made 9 commands with 10 bullets and 1 command with 5 bullets. And you have submitted these commands to Invoker, now invoker doesn't have to worry about how much bullets are left. He will just execute the command. On the other hand if invoker has to provide the no of bullets at run time then it could be the case supplied number of bullets are not available.

My point here is that Invoker must not have to worry about any extra information needs to execute the command. And as mentioned in wiki "an object is used to encapsulate all information needed to perform an action or trigger an event at a later time"

Comment: Would the Strategy pattern be better?

Comment: I don't think strategy pattern would  be best for this use case. Example you have provided is good fit for command pattern.

Comment: So, you're saying, it's fine to have the number of bullets in the constructor, correct?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: What would be wrong with the strategy pattern? I tried it and the code is a lot shorter and more understandable

Comment: Suppose you have defined 2 strategies with no of bullets 3, 5 and there are total 10 bullets. Then there 2(5+3) or 1(3*3) bullets will always be left. I suppose there could be other cases also. Please correct me if I am missing anything

Comment: As define by wiki and several answers here, the command pattern is fine as I've specified. Thanks

Comment: @Nexusfactor That is the problem. Why don't you pick up the Gamma Book(GoF) and prefer it over Wikipedia, or the milieu of persistently shifting views  anywhere on the web, including StackOverflow(no offense to anyone who hangs out here; I do to).

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. Because GoF is guidelines, not mandates. Opinions (which is what GoF is), patterns, paradigms, etc. all change.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree. Which is why (in my opinion) they were conceptualized to be so mutable in terms of integration and modularity. Good point!

Answer (score -1):

### Using the Command Pattern with Parameters

Consider the related '*Extension Patterns*' in order to hold to a Top-Down Control paradigm '*Inversion of Control*'.
This pattern, the Command Pattern, is commonly used in concert with the **Composite**, **Iterator**, and **Visitor Design Patterns.**
Commands are '*First Class Objects*'. So it is critical that the integrity of their encapsulation is protected. Also, inverting Control From Top Down to Bottom Up, Violates a Cardinal principle of Object Oriented Design, though I see people suggesting it all of the time...

The Composite pattern will allow you to store Commands, in iterative data structures.

Before going any further, and while your code is still manageable, look at these Patterns.

There are some reasonable points made here in this thread. @Loc has it closest IMO, However, If you consider the patterns mentioned above, then, regardless of the scope of your project (it appears that you intend to make a game, no small task) you will be able to remain in control of lower-level dependency. As @Loc pointed out, with 'Dependency Injection' lower class Objects should be kept 'in the dark' when it comes to any specific implementation, in terms of the data that is consumed by them; this is (should be) reserved for the top level hierarchy. 'Programming to Interfaces, not Implementation'.

It seems that you have a notion of this. Let me just point out where I see a likely mistake at this point. Actually a couple, already, you are focused on grains of sand I.e. "Bullets" you are not at the point where trivialities like that serve any purpose, except to be a cautionary sign, that you are presently about to lose control of higher level dependencies.

Whether you are able to see it yet or not, granular parts can and should be dealt with at higher levels. I will make a couple of suggestions. @Loc already mentioned the best practice 'Constructor Injection' loosely qualified, better to maybe look up this term 'Dependency Injection'.

Take the Bullets for e.g. Since they have already appeared on your scope. The Composite Pattern is designed to deal with many differing yet related First Class Objects e.g. Commands. Between the Iterator and Visitor Patterns you are able to store all of your pre-instantiated Commands, and future instantiations as well, in a dynamic data structure, like a Linked List OR a Binary Search Tree even. At this point forget about the Strategy
Pattern, A few possible scenarios is one thing, but It makes no sense to be writing adaptive interfaces at the outset.

Another thing, I see no indication that you are spawning projectiles from a class, bullets I mean. However, even if it were just a matter of keeping track of weapon configurations, and capacities(int items) (I'm only guessing that is the cause of necessary changes in projectile counts) use a stack structure or depending on what the actual scenario is; a circular queue. If you are actually spawning projectiles from a factory, or if you decide to in the future, you are ready to take advantage of Object Pooling; which, as it turns out, was motivated by this express consideration.

Not that anyone here has done this, but I find it particularly asinine for someone to suggest that it is ok to mishandle or disregard a particular motivation behind any established (especially GoF) Design pattern. If you find yourself having to modify a GoF Design pattern, then you are using the wrong one. Just sayin'

P.S. if you absolutely must, why don't you instead, use a template solution, rather than alter an intentionally specific Interface design;