# How to use the Command Pattern when dealing with different parameters

Tags: design-patterns

Having a look at the UML diagrams for the Command Pattern reported [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm), the class of the invoker object (the one that inkoves the `execute()` method of a command object) *must* provide a `setCommand()` method to allow the client code to set the proper command object on the invoker: but how can such method be used when dealing with command objects that have **different parameters** which, additionally, are known only at runtime? I'll try to make an example.

```php
class Messenger
{
  public function sendEmail(string $email, string $subject, string $body): void { ... }
  public function sendSms(string $phone, string $text): void { ... }
}

interface Command
{
  public function execute(): void;
}

class SendEmailCommand implements Command
{
  private readonly Messenger $messenger;
  private readonly string $email;
  private readonly string $subject;
  private readonly string $body;

  public function __constructor(Messenger $messenger)
  {
    $this->messenger = $messenger;
  }

  public function setEmail(string $email): void { $this->email = $email; }
  public function setSubject(string $subject): void { $this->subject = $subject; }
  public function setBody(string $body): void { $this->body = $body; }

  public function execute(): void
  {
    $this->messenger->sendEmail($this->email, $this->subject, $this->body);
  }
}

class SendSmsCommand implements Command
{
  private readonly Messenger $messenger;
  private readonly string $phone;
  private readonly string $text;

  public function __constructor(Messenger $messenger)
  {
    $this->messenger = $messenger;
  }

  public function setPhone(string $phone): void { $this->phone = $phone; }
  public function setText(string $text): void { $this->text = $text; }

  public function execute(): void
  {
    $this->messenger->sendSms($this->phone, $this->text);
  }
}
```

In such a scenario how much is it useful to have a `setCommand(Command $command)` on the invoker class? In some languages I would even get an error later when trying to call `setX()` because the `Command` interface doesn't define them. Would it be a bad idea to do something like this?

```php
class EmailSendButton()
{
  private readonly Messenger $messenger;

  public function __constructor(Messenger $messenger)
  {
    $this->messenger = $messenger;
  }

  public function onClick(): void
  {
    $email = $this->getEmail();
    $subject = $this->getSubject();
    $body = $this->getBody();

    $sendEmailCommand = new SendEmailCommand($this->messenger);
    $sendEmailCommand->setEmail($email);
    $sendEmailCommand->setSubject($subject);
    $sendEmailCommand->setBody($body);
    $sendEmailCommand->execute();
  }
}
```

I know it is not ideal to instantiate a class inside another class, it creates coupling, but how would you solve it?

I was thinking about `setCommand(SendEmailCommand $sendEmailCommand)` instead of the easier `setCommand(Command $command)` but it adds more complexity on the client code than benefits IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command pattern is the command a single instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747238/command-pattern-is-the-command-a-single-instance)

Comment: Most likely the Command Pattern doesn't help you here, because you don't need to separate instantiation from invocation, as the last example shows.

Answer (score 0):

> I know it is not ideal to instantiate a class inside another class, it creates coupling, but how would you solve it?

It looks like you want to have various commands which can have different parameters. I am not familiar with php, so let me show an example how to accomplish it via C#. The main idea is to create a custom class which implements `ICommand` interface. Having had such a class, you can send any params that you want.

So let's dive in code.

This is an abstraction of `Command`:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

These are concrete implemetations of `Command` abstraction. These implemetations can have different parameters:

```
class SmsCommand : ICommand
{
    private string _phone;
    private string _text;
    private Messenger _messenger;


    public SmsCommand(string phone, string text, Messenger messenger)
    {
        _phone = phone;
        _text= text;
        _messenger= messenger;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _messenger.SendSms(_phone, _text);
    }
}
```

And `EmailCommand`:

```
class EmailCommand : ICommand
{
    private string _phone;
    private string _text;
    private string _subject;
    private string _body;
    private Messenger _messenger;
    
    public EmailCommand(string phone, string text, string subject, 
        string body, Messenger messenger)
    {
        _phone = phone;
        _text = text;
        _subject = subject;
        _body = body;
        _messenger = messenger;
    }

    
    public void Execute()
    {
        _messenger.SendEmail(_phone, _text, _subject, _body);
    }
}
```

And it is `Messenger` which can send messages that you want:

```
public class Messenger
{
    public void SendEmail(string phone, string text, 
        string subject, string body)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"EmailCommand: phone: {phone}, text: {text}" +
            $" subject: {subject} , body:  {body}");
    }

    public void SendSms(string phone, string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SmsCommand: phone: {phone}, text: {text}");
    }
}
```

This is a class which runs the above commands:

```
public class Invoker
{
    ICommand _command;

    public void SetCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        _command = command;
    }
    public void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        _command.Execute();
    }
}
```

And the above code can be run like this:

```
Invoker invoker = new Invoker();
invoker.SetCommand(new SmsCommand("phone 1", "text 1", new Messenger()));
invoker.ExecuteCommand();

invoker.SetCommand(new EmailCommand("phone 1", "text 1", 
    "subject 1", "body 1", new Messenger()));
invoker.ExecuteCommand();
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

The great article about command pattern [can be seen here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command/csharp/example).